# Sharepoint page redirection for unauthorised users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, redirect

Is it possible, if so how(!), to auto redirect a user that doesnt have access to a certain page?

I can see that in many cases this could be a complete pain for a user and confusing, but in my situation it would be ideal.

Thx in advance!

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can do it by creating a custom HTTP Module, which can override the default access denied page.

[Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/ketaanhs/archive/2009/03/16/moss-sharepoint-2007-custom-error-page-and-access-denied-page.aspx).

Comment: ok I'll take a look...never written a sharepoint module...so keep an eye out for a question about that!!! :-)

Comment: @SteveCI, no problems, just ask away. Added an example link.

Answer (score -1):

You can customise the accessdenied.aspx file in layouts folder.

Before customising it you need to take a copy.

with the writing of javascript (location.href=new file) code you can redirect user to other page.

Comment: No no, please don't modify the OOB files in SharePoint. It's bad practice and will leave your SharePoint installation in an unsupported state.

Comment: yeah im not really a fan of doing this.
also, ideally i only want to apply the redirect to one page.

Comment: create a blank aspx page and give the name as accessdenied.aspx and write <script language="javascript">location.href="[url of new page]"</script>. then deploy this page layouts folder. thats it.